# Songs Package Index Generation

Tags: indexing, songs

First of all I have to say I’m Spanish, so I’m sorry for any mistakes in my English. Also, I’m very new at LaTeX.

I'm using the songs package to create a songs book. I've been able to typeset songs with chords but I cant find the way to generate a “Title Index” or an “Author Index” at the beginning of the book.

I have these lines at the beginning:

```
\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{authidx}
```

I use these lines to show my indexes:

```
\showindex[2]{Índex de títols}{titleidx}
```

and

```
\showindex[2]{Índex de d'autors}{authidx}
```

And my songs are written between:

```
\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx}
```

... songs ...

```
\end{songs}
```

I checked the Songs package documentation and it seems that I need to use a program named “songsidx”. Where do I find it and how exactly do I use it to generate my indexes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `songidx` program was written in order to sort scripture references.

## [image: Windows] Windows

If you use Windows, there's a self-installing executable named `songs-<version.number>-setup.exe` available for download which contains a binary `songidx.exe` ready for you to use. The current version of `songs` is `2.15`, so you can download [`songs-2.15-setup.exe`](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/songs/songs-2.15-setup.exe?download) available in the project homepage (link is provided).

## [image: Unix] Unix

For Unix, we have some work to do beforehand. Let's build the program from source, so we need to obtain a file named `songs-<version.number>.tar.gz` and unpack it. The current version of `songs` is `2.15`, so you can download [`songs-2.15.tar.gz`](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/songs/songs-2.15.tar.gz?download) available in the project homepage (link is provided).

In terminal, go to the same directory you have downloaded `songs-2.15.tar.gz` and run:

```
$ tar xvzf songs-2.15.tar.gz
```

A directory named `songs-2.15` will be created in the current directory. Let's enter in this directory with the command

```
$ cd songs-2.15
```

Now, we have to configure our build process. Run

```
$ ./configure
```

and wait a couple of seconds. After it ends, it's actually time to build everything! Go with

```
$ make
```

and go have some ice cream while everything is built. `:)` When finished, our `songidx` program is now build inside `src/songidx/`.

Copy `songidx` to your current project directory (if you want to specify which version of the bible you wish to use as a basis for sorting your scripture index, copy the corresponding `.can` file as well). Now let's take a look at the usage.

## [image: Usage] Usage

Now let's see a real example. I wrote this humble `.tex` file based on your initial setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{songs}

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{authidx}

\begin{document}

\showindex[2]{Índex de títols}{titleidx}
\showindex[2]{Índex de d'autors}{authidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx}

\beginsong{Mi alma glorifica al Señor, mi Dios}[by={Tradicional}]

\begin{chorus}
Mi \[E]alma glorifica al Señor, mi \[B7]Dios,
\[C#m]gózase mi espíritu en mi Salva\[G#m]dor.
\[A]El es mi ale\[B7]gría, \[E]es mi pleni\[C#m]tud,
\[A6]El es todo \[B7]para \[E]mí.
\end{chorus}

\begin{verse}
\[G#] Ha mi\[C#m]rado la ba\[G#]jeza de su es\[C#m]clava,
muy di\[B7]chosa me dirán todos los \[E]pueblos
porque en \[C#7]mí ha hecho grandes mara\[F#m]villas
El que \[C#m]todo puede, \[G#]cuyo Nombre es \[C#m]Santo. \[B7]
\end{verse}

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Let's call this file `cancionero.tex`. First of all, let's run our favourite engine on this file:

```
$ pdflatex cancionero.tex
```

Based on our setup, two files will be generated, `titleidx.sxd` and `authidx.sxd`. Now it's time to use `songidx` on them:

```
$ ./songidx titleidx.sxd titleidx.sbx
```

and

```
$ ./songidx authidx.sxd authidx.sbx
```

Then, let's run our engine again to organize everything:

```
$ pdflatex cancionero.tex
```

The output follows. First of all, we have `\showindex[2]{Índex de títols}{titleidx}`, our index of titles:

[image: Titles]

Then, our index of authors, thanks to `\showindex[2]{Índex de d'autors}{authidx}`:

[image: Authors]

And at last but not least, our song:

[image: Song]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Hello @Paul Cereda, do you have any idea how this works in a mac?

Comment: @Mercy: Hi! `:)` The build instructions for Unix should work in a Mac as well, provided that you have `gcc` installed (via Xcode or homebrew). Then the usage of `songidx` is the same. The author only provides Windows binaries; for Mac or Linux, we need to compile the tool from source.

Comment: A couple of notes. on OS X as of this writing in the preamble we need to add `\newcommand{\songlink}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}
`. Also when using `xelatex`, the `authidx.sbx` file doesn't get generated, but running `./songidx` with just the `authidx.sxd` seems to work.