# Multiple Figure Classes with titletoc

Tags: titletoc, music, songs, songbook

Following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130203/68905), I'm hoping to track multiple types of figures in an `extbook` document, rendered with XeLaTeX.

What I'm doing is using one "class" of figure to display sheet music for *songs*, and another to display *pictures*. I may not even need a list of figures for pictures, but at the very least, they shouldn't be popping up in the song "index".

Using `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)`.

I would expect the output of the code below to render two different lists: The first listing six *songs*, 1 – 6, and the second with three *pictures*, 1 – 3. Two lists are created, but the song list only contains three items, 6 – 8, and the second list contains six — three *songs* and three *pictures*, numbered 1 – 5, 9.

I admit to only having scanned the [docs](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), which don't actually explain how `\resumeList` is supposed to work, so I imagine there is either an incompatibility with the document class or I am misunderstanding how the package is supposed to work and/or be used.

Also wondering if my overall approach to creating a list of Songs is the best one.

```
% arara: lilypond: {options: "--latex-program=xelatex --pdf"}
% arara: xelatex: { files: [ 'sandbox.tex' ] }
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext} % for filler
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler

\newcommand\songFigure{% just to quickly generate captioned images in the document
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{song figure~\thefigure}
    \end{figure}%
}
\newcommand\imageFigure{% just to quickly generate captioned images in the document
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{image figure~\thefigure}
    \end{wrapfigure}%
}
\begin{document}
\startlist[song]{lof}% start list of Song figures
\printlist[song]{lof}{}{\chapter*{List of Song Figures}} % print main list of song figures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\songFigure
\songFigure
\songFigure

\stoplist[song]{lof}% stop list of songs
\startlist[image]{lof}% start list of images

\imageFigure

\lipsum[1]

\imageFigure

\lipsum[2-3]

\stoplist[image]{lof}% stop list of pictures
\resumelist[song]{lof}% resume list of songs

\songFigure
\songFigure
\songFigure

\appendix
\clearpage
\stoplist[song]{lof}% stop list of songs
\resumelist[image]{lof}% resume list of images

\imageFigure

\lipsum[2-3]
\stoplist[image]{lof}% stop list of pictures
\printlist[image]{lof}{}{\chapter*{List of images}} % print list of images
\end{document}
```

[image: Song Figure Listing]
[image: Image Figure Listing]

Comment: This may be another / better approach... http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122033/68905